# django postgresql query not working

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, postgresql

I have a postgreSQL database that has a table `foo` that I've created outside of django. I used `manage.py inspectdb` to build the model for table `foo` for me. This technique worked fine when I was using MySQL but with PostgreSQL it is failing MISERABLY. The table is multiple gigabytes and I build it from a text file with PostgreSQL 'COPY'.

I can run raw queries on table `foo` and everything executes and expected.

For example

```
foo.objects.raw('bar_sql')
```

executes as expected.

But running queries like:

```
foo.objects.get(bar=bar)
```

throw

```
ProgrammingError column foo.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "foo"."id", "foo"."bar1", "all_...
```

`foo` doesn't innately have an `id` field. As I understand it django is suppose to create one. Have I some how subverted this step when creating the tables outside of django?

Queries run on models whose table was populated threw django run as expected in all cases.

I'm missing something very basic here and any help would be appreciated.

I'm using django 1.6 with postgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: How does your table and model look like? Django may have failed to recognize wich column is the PK, hence it looks for "id", the default. Your model should have a field with pimary_key =True

Comment: Thank you for your help. Youre absolutely correct. I never set a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't modify your existing database tables. It only creates new tables. If you have existing tables, it usually doesn't touch them at all.

"As I understand it django is suppose to create one." --> It only adds a primary key to a table when it creates it, which means you don't need to specify that explicitly in your model, but it won't do anything to an existing table.

So if for example you later on decide to add fields to your models, you have to update your databases manually.

What you need to do in your case is that by doing manual database administration make sure that your table has a primary key, and also that the name of the primary key is "id" (although I am not sure if this is necessary, it is better to do it.) So use a database administration tool, modify your table and add the primary key, and name it id. Then it should start working.